# AIDL stub leaking memory(Activity)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, aidl, leakcanary

I am trying to find memory leak. LeakCanary saying `(Anonymous subclass of com.xxx.xxx.aidl.TempAIDL$Stub)
Instance of com.xxx.xxx.TempActivity$1`

**Problem**: I believe my AIDL stub is leaking memory (Activity)

**More information**:

1. In my stub. I am not accessing activity context.
2. Using the stub, I am registering the service  and unregistering in onPause of activity.
3. Inside stub, there are various method which access the views(multiple
   views which are declared at class level) and perform some operation
   with it.
4. The stub is defined as follows.

`private final TempAIDL.Stub = new     TempAIDL.Stub() { ....... }`

I am trying to figure out

1. what could be the possiblities that stub is responsible for leak?
2. Is stub responsible?
3. I am guessing the leak is because I am accessing the view inside the
   stub. Am I correct?

Comment: In information section, I'm confused about point 4: you declared Stub in Service class, didn't you? How do you interact with views inside the Stub - point 3? You probably right, if you access views inside the stub, which means views context are being interacted with outside the activity lifecycle, therefore it could produce memory leak

Comment: Sorry, you re correct it is defined. I have edited 4th point

Comment: Sorry, about confusion. Point 4: I have defined Stub in Activity. Point 3: The view for eg. TextView is declared on class level and initialize in the onCreate method. Hence, inside stub I m manipulating the views(TextView or other child views)

Comment: So any ideas How to solve this? How about inner static class?

Comment: Stub is attached with Service.onBind(), plus Service has its own life-cycle, however view is attached with Activity's context. I think if you want to interact with views, you should do it under ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected() instead of inside the Stub, which is the callback when the activity is binding to the Service

Comment: When using Binder, you must ensure the service connection is binded. So that any interaction with views under Stub is potentially memory-leak. If you want to achieve different operations, consider using listener pattern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184988/discussion-between-giang-nguyen-and-akshay-taru).